# Multi level inheritance in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a method from class A and apply it to a value in class C:

```
class A
{
    //my code here
    public virtual string calculatebnft()
    {
        string bnft = "";
        //my code here
        return bnft;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    //my code here
    public override string calculatebnft()
    {
        string bnft = "";
        //my code here
        return bnft;
    }
}

class C : B
{
    //my code here
}
```

In my Main method:

```
C c1=new C();
//my code here
string bnft=c1.calculatebnft();
MessageBox.Show(bnft);
```

When I run program it always runs class B's method calculatebnft(). How can I call calculatebnft() from A instead? The rest of code from B "which is working correctly".

Comment: If the runtime type of your object is at least `B` it will always run the method from `B` (unless it is declared as `new`, but then it's actually a different method)

Comment: Even though you can achieve it, you might want to reconsider. I think most folks would (understandably) expect that if your class inherits from `B`, then it should utilize `B`'s implementation of methods; otherwise, it makes more sense as a parallel implementation of `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that without changing `B` code. You have to change `calculatebnft` method from `override` to `new`:

```
class B : A
{
    //my code here
    public new string calculatebnft()
    {
        string bnft = "";
        //my code here
        return bnft;
    }
}
```

with that you could do following:

```
string bngt = ((A)c1).calculatebnft();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the outside there is no way to call a base class instance of a virtual method.  It is simply not possible because it is forbidden by the CLR (possible, but not verifiable).  The only way to get access to it is for `A` or `B` to give you another method on which to call the functionality.  For example

```
class A {
  public string callMe() { 
   return ...;
  }

  public virtual string calculatebnft() {
    return callMe();
  }
}
```

Now a caller who wants the `A` version of `calculatebnft` can use `callMe` instead.

In general though I'd consider this bad practice.  If there is a situation where you really wanted the base class version of a virtual method then it's probably not the best method to be virtual.

Comment: +1 exactly what I was about to post. Can you elaborate a bit on *possible, but not verifiable*?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel at an IL level you can issue a .call (non virtual method of calling) on `A::calculatebnft` and it would do the trick.  This essentially how a `base.calculatebnft` would be issued.  But when done from outside the class hierarchy it's considered unverifiable code

Comment: What you mean by unverifiable here? CLR will throw `InvalidProgramException` in that case? or something else?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel tools like peverify will say that it's incorrect.  It can be loaded in the CLR under full trust but I doubt it would load under say partial trust

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible this way.

But for example you can do something like this:

```
class A
{
    //my code here
    public virtual string calculatebnft()
    {
        string bnft = "A";
        //my code here
        return bnft;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public string calculatebnftFromA()
    {
        return base.calculatebnft();
    }

    //my code here
    public override string calculatebnft()
    {
        string bnft = "B";
        //my code here
        return bnft;
    }
}
```